Is there a correct way to do PID/TID caching?
Consider the following code:
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    pid_t tid = gettid();
    printf("tid: %d", tid); 
    int ret = syscall(SYS_fork, 0);
    printf("tid: %d", gettid()); 
}


With modern (>=2.25) glibc, the above will print three lines with two different values.
With musl, however, the above will give three identical lines.

The difference is due to caching. libc implementation tries to avoid the overhead due to syscall so such values are cached. The fork/clone wrappers are in charge of updating the values but user may bypass such wrappers, leading to unexpected results.
The manpage of getpid has a special section talking about the history:

From glibc 2.3.4 up to and including glibc 2.24, the glibc
wrapper function for getpid() cached PIDs, with the goal of
avoiding additional system calls when a process calls getpid()
repeatedly.  Normally this caching was invisible, but its correct
operation relied on support in the wrapper functions for fork(2),
vfork(2), and clone(2): if an application bypassed the glibc
wrappers for these system calls by using syscall(2), then a call
to getpid() in the child would return the wrong value (to be
precise: it would return the PID of the parent process).  In
addition, there were cases where getpid() could return the wrong
value even when invoking clone(2) via the glibc wrapper function.
(For a discussion of one such case, see BUGS in clone(2).)
Furthermore, the complexity of the caching code had been the
source of a few bugs within glibc over the years.

I wonder if there is still a way to do the caching properly. Given that MADV_WIPEONFORK will instruct the kernel to wipe certain pages on fork, can we create the following structure:
struct ProcessLocalStorage {
  OnceFlag once; /* zero represents uninitialized */
  pid_t pid;
  pid_t getpid() {
    callonce(&this->once, []{ pid = syscall(SYS_getpid); });
    return pid;
  }
} *pls = mmap(...); /* hinted by MADV_WIPEONFORK */

pid_t gettid() {
  static thread_local pid_t pid = 0;
  static thread_local pid_t tid = 0;
  pid_t real_pid = pls->getpid();
  if (pid != real_pid) {
      pid = real_pid;
      tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
  }
  return tid;
}

One problem I can think of is that user calls SYS_clone on their own without setting up TLS properly but I think we can say that users should not assume libc to work under such scenarios.

That lambda looks like C++, not C. So does &this.

The function defined within the structure type is also C++.

Are you sure that the calls to getpid() or gettid() are a real bottleneck in your code?  If not, why bother with the cacheing?

Consider recursive mutex implementation, syscall means that each lock/trylock will have overhead.

@JonathanLeffler sorry for using c++. The design discussion is for implementing gettid/getpid in libc so I left it in C category.

The fork/clone wrappers are in charge of updating the values but user may bypass such wrappers, leading to unexpected results  Given that, what is the point of bypassing the libc fork() call?  You're putting a lot of effort into this, but the fundamental problem being solved remains unknown.  What problem does bypassing libc's fork() function with a direct system all solve?  If you're trying to cover for some developers getting too "clever" for their own good, I'd say file bug reports on them for creating code so broken you can't even reliably get a process's PID/TID any more.

@AndrewHenle I do see MUSL and bionic still use cached PID/TIDs. Do you think it is fair to claim that a libc implementation does not support bypassed fork/clone? If so, I can open a RFC to decide the behavior.
Another interesting thing is that even with wrappers, if a signal happens right after the sys_clone, the signal handler may get the wrong answer. So, one must be careful in implementing such wrappers (for instance, invalid the cache before clone/fork).

@SchrodingerZHU From what you've posted so far, I'd say glibc doesn't support bypassing fork()/clone().  But then glibc's fork() is so broken its maintainers engaged in a decades-long campaign that wore down the POSIX committee to the point they finally acquiesced in removing fork() from the POSIX list of functions required to be async-signal-safe. So glibc mucking things up around a fork() call isn't exactly new information. They couldn't get a POSIX requirement right and literally fought to have the standard lowered so they could meet it. I don't think "should" will work.

@AndrewHenle Interesting. Given that pthread_atfork is also in POSIX, I would argue that a libc user should not use bypassed fork unless they are really aware what they are doing. So, I think it is plausible to cache these PIDs/TIDs anyway. Unfortunately, according to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html, getpid is async-signal-safe (gettid is not), so I think I cannot cache it trivially (i.e. I will need to invalid the cache before fork/clone and then recover it).

@SchrodingerZHU pthread_atfork() is specified with "If a fork() call in a multi-threaded process leads to a child fork handler calling any function that is not async-signal-safe, the behavior is undefined."  So if you do create a fork() handler that's not async-signal-safe, it'd be you that broke things.  I'm pretty sure that's one of the things glibc does - it creates non-async-signal-safe fork() handlers - in an OS-wide shared library.  "Mom, the children got into the source code again!"
